# Modular Website Design, with ASP.NET MVC, I want a less-monolithic design

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture

I want to build websites in a modular fashion, so I can get better code reuse and abstract away some implementation details. I'm looking for advice on how to code such a website with ASP.NET and Visual Studio, and modules for such a website, because at the moment my websites don't have this nice property.

At the moment I'm working on a web-app that's providing a pretty straight-forward internally facing contact manager for a company. We plan on using identical contact managers (pointing to different databases) for each of our independent customer-facing websites (each for one of the company's businesses). I'm using ASP.NET MVC in C# with EntityFramework. What I'd like, is to be able to simply drop this contact manager package/project/class-library into a Visual Studio solution for an ASP.NET MVC Website, and then just add whatever 'wiring' I need to get them working together. I've seen the use of "areas" within MVC apps, that basically function as mini MVC applications, but it's been messy and actually less maintainable because of configs and different areas wanting different versions of assemblies (this is not code I wrote, and I want to avoid writing code like this). I have an idea of what this would look like in terms of data-objects and box&line diagrams; unfortunately, I don't know what this looks like in terms of views, controllers, projects, or assemblies.

The thing is, as a relatively unseasoned programmer, I've never done this before, so need advice on how to proceed. I'm unfamiliar with the patterns/idioms I need to implement this. So while I have the theoretical knowledge of how to write nice modular software architectures, I don't know they end up looking like in-terms of their actual classes, namespaces, and Visual Studio Projects/Solutions.

My question is, how do I build a website that's more modular than your standard MVC? And, if you have experience doing this (or attempting to), could you please share it? Or even better, can you offer a concrete example of such an architecture? (note this will probably require a link to something not on stack overflow, since you can't copy and paste an entire code-base to stackoverflow).

Apologies for not having a specific question, but this is a bit more complicated than a simple query of "how to traverse a b-tree", "why isn't my code compiling", "does anyone have a regex to do the thing I want", "I wrote some terrible code and now it broke", and "I haven't read the documentation (assuming there is any) and now I'm getting an exception that I don't understand". There likely isn't a single answer, because programming is complicated, solving real-world problems takes thought, and writing good code can be hard. Also, I can't exactly post the code I'm working with because of this thing in my contract known as a confidentiality clause, and not that anyone would read through 100's of thousands of lines of code and tell me how to make it better. \end_rant

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic in this forum.

Comment: I really like [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/) as a learning tool.  You should check that out.

Comment: I think the question might have been worded better, but OP is looking for architectural solution recommendation, which of course involves the right "tools" / technologies, not "tools" per se even though he mentions it in the question.

Comment: Well 'tools' is not always clear, I'm not asking which IDE, language, or keyboard to use. But, I am asking what libraries, VS features, and resources I should use to solve a programming problem. So, I'm asking how I should go about using the tools I have, which isn't much different than asking what code I should write or why is my code broken. Which is like asking, "what language tools (syntax) should I use, and why is the tool I wrote broken"). Point being, 'tool' doesn't have the best definition in the software world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the "Onion Architecture".

[image: onion architecture]

**[Here's a live implementation of the Onion Architecture](https://github.com/duncanhunter/WebAPI2-Onion-Architecture-SSW-Style-with-DI-and-UOW)** over on GitHub that uses Web API, MVC etc. It uses the all familiar Northwind database. So you can browse through the code and solution after you learn about this architecture and make sense of it and incorporate the parts you need in your project / solution.

Also, **[here's a nice tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20160523073831/http://blog.dkmulligan.com/2013/05/16/onion-architecture/)** on how to develop using this approach.

Finally, a Channel 9 Video that was what I originally found a few years back when I was researching the same thing, and found it very useful.

#### [ASP.NET MVC Solution Best Practices](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/ASP-NET-MVC-Solution-Best-Practices)

This video also takes an existing monolithic project and turns it into an Onion Architecture implementation, along with reasoning on why we are doing what at every step.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, I'll let you know if it is after I look at what you linked. Thanks!

Comment: That's a slick graphic; is that from Microsoft?

Comment: Not sure. It's from one of the blogs I linked to in my answer. =>http://blog.dkmulligan.com/2013/05/16/onion-architecture/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to direct yourself in implementing your systems based on an approach that can provide complex systems that will not make everyone furious in waiting.

This is commonly known as the [Domain-Driven design](http://dddcommunity.org/).

Then comes SOLID. SOLID represents architectural choices that will make your system easy to maintain and extend.

[See SOLID in action using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp)

All these along with [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html) can keep you busy for all your career and yet it could not be enough.

trying to follow the above in your programming will give you eventually a "less-monolithic" system and modular.

In ASP.NET MVC terms the above could mean:

- Keep the MVC paradigm. Do not feed your controllers more than they should eat. Keep them only for what they are. Traffic cops. Also do not put logic in your views in order to keep them abstracted.
- Maintain your logic in a separate "space". By the word "space" i mean a separate project, solution, assembly....whatever you think fits to your application size that you are building.
- Use MVC Areas for what they are supposed to be. They fit perfectly for the FrontEnd / Admin case. You want to have a frontend that looks and operates differently from the backend, but obeys some general system rules.
- Use Web API to make your application open and expendable. This will bring Javascript into play which itself needs to be addressed regarding SOLID e.t.c..
- Do not overdose your application with javascript frameworks just for the shake of it. Use what you really need.
- Use IoC container like [Ninject](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-use-ninject-2-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) to manage your dependencies..Marry your interfaces and let IoC resolve your implementations
- If you going deep in javascript , take your time to define your viewmodels correctly. They are the contracts between 2 different worlds so they must be clear.